# Conditional PDFs from a Derived Variable

Tags: probability

I have two PDFs, one exponential and one uniform:

$f_x(x) = $
\begin{cases}
\lambda e^{-\lambda x},  & \text{x $\gt$ 0} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

$f_y(y) = $
\begin{cases}
(b-a)^{-1},  & \text{a $\le$ y $\le$ b} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

Y and X are both independent random variables and b > a > 0.

$Z = X + Y^2$

If I create a new variable called Z as shown above, I'm looking to find the conditional PDF:

$f_{z|x}(z|x)$ in order to find $f_{z,x}(z,x) = f_x(x)f_{z|x}(z|x)$

My approach so far has been this:

I know that: $f_{x,y}(x,y) = f_x(x)f_y(y)$ because X & Y are independent.

$f_{x,y}(x,y) = $
\begin{cases}
\lambda e^{-\lambda x}(b-a)^{-1},  & \text{a $\le$ y $\le$ b, a $\le$ x $\le$ b} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

Since, the condition probability of Z given X means X is fixed:

$Y = \pm\sqrt{Z-X}$

$f_{z|x}(z|x) = $
\begin{cases}
f_{x,y}(x,\sqrt{Z-X}) ,  & \text{a $\le$ $\sqrt{Z-X}$ $\le$ b, a $\le$ x $\le$ b} \\
f_{x,y}(x,-\sqrt{Z-X}), & \text{a $\le$ $-\sqrt{Z-X}$ $\le$ b, a $\le$ x $\le$ b}
\end{cases}

By eliminating y in the joint PDF of x & y, am I able to obtain the conditional pdf correctly? There is something wrong with the limits in the conditional PDF because, they contradict each other.  I'm kind of stuck at this point.

Using the strategy of finding the CDF first of $F_T$:

$F_{Y}(y) = $
\begin{cases}
(y-a)/(b-a),  & \text{a $\le$ $y$ $\le$ b} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

$F_{T}(t) = P(T \le t) = P(Y^2 \le t) = P(-\sqrt{t} \le Y \le \sqrt{t}) = F_Y(\sqrt{t}) - F_Y(-\sqrt{t})$

$F_{T}(t) = $
\begin{cases}
(\sqrt{t}-a)/(b-a),  & \text{$a^2$ $\le$ $t$ $\le$ $b^2$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

Typically I would take the derivative of the CDF $F_T(t)$ and move onto the second part of the route suggested by user "did". However, the CDF is not equal to one for t = $b^2$. This doesn't seem right.

$f_{T}(t) = $
\begin{cases}
((b-a)^{-1}/(2\sqrt{t}),  & \text{$a^2$ $\le$ $t$ $\le$ $b^2$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

Then using the equation in the comments:

$f_{X,Z}(X,Z) = $
\begin{cases}
(f_x(x)(b-a)^{-1}/(2\sqrt{z-x}),  & \text{$a^2+x$ $\le$ $z$ $\le$ $x+b^2, x > 0$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

Comment: Simpler: Assume that $T=Y^2$ has PDF $f_T$, then the PDF of $(X,Z)$ with $Z=X+T$ is $$f_{X,Z}(x,z)=f_X(x)f_T(z-x).$$ When applying this, please watch out for the case when $a<0<b$ (which yields more complicated formulas for the PDF $f_T$, maybe you are supposed to assume that $0<a<b$?) and please correct $f_X$ into $$f_X(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\mathbf 1_{x>0}.$$

Comment: Thank you. $f_T(t)$ would still be a uniform variable, the limits and the value of the pdf in those limits would change. I'll take a closer look.

Comment: No, if $Y$ is uniform, say on $(a,b)$ with $b>a>0$, then $T=Y^2$ is not uniform on $(a^2,b^2)$.

Comment: Please see my edits above. So I can find the pdf of T by taking the derivative of $F_T(t)$ but I am concerned that $F_T(t)$ is incorrect because $F_T(b^2)$ is not equal to 1.

Comment: If $b>a>0$ then $F_Y(-\sqrt{t})=0$ for every $t>0$.

Comment: Okay, so $F_Y(y)$ is zero for negative y values because it's PDF is defined in the area where a or b is less than zero as zero. In your first comment when you said: $f_{X,Z}(x,z) = f_X(x)f_T(z-x)$. This implies that $f_{Z|X}(z|x) = f_T(z-x)$. Why do we take $f_T(t)$ as the function to plug $z-x$?

Comment: Because we have general approaches to the computation of the joint distributions of transforms of random vectors. Which ones do you know?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30838/discussion-between-bud-and-did).